# How do I correctly map letters in the database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have two tables. One table with the letters of different countries and a second table with a mapping of these letters to each other.

I need to make a query to get the mapped letters of the two languages. Can you tell me how this can be done optimally?

The letter table

| id | letter | language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | en |
| 2 | Ä | de |
| 3 | A | de |
| 4 | O | en |
| 5 | O | de |
| 6 | Ö | de |

The letter mapping table

| id | letter1(letterTable.id) | letter2(letterTable.id) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 6 |

Would it be better to create a separate table for each alphabet?

Maybe there is some other architectural approach for this kind of letter matching? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Note that the `id` column in the mapping table is unnecessary. Just make `(letter1,letter2)` the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a join that is restricted to the two languages you want to check:

```
select en.id as id_en, 
       en.letter as letter_en, 
       de.id as id_de,
       de.letter as letter_de
from letter en
  join letter_mapping lm on lm.letter1 = en.id
  join letter de on de.id = lm.letter2 and de.language = 'de'
where en.language = 'en';
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/i45of7Wk)